# How can I easily analyze Firebase A/B test results with event parameters?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

We use Firebase A/B test product for our mobile apps. We need to reach the parameters of our events and make a deeper analyze. We have worked with BigQuery before for this, but it requires a lot of effort.

Let me tell you briefly about our problem:

Let's say we have an event called **add_to_cart**. We want to look at the number of times the add_to_cart is triggered from a **specific screen** in the A/B test results. For example, those whose **firebase screen class** is **category_page**. This data can be accessed by writing a query over BigQuery, but create extra effort for different needs.

Is there a short way or tool about doing analysis by event parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we find Firebase's reporting and analysis insufficient, we will decide to use a different tool. If anyone encounters such a problem, it is possible to make a deep analysis through **BigQuery**.

Another way you can use Audience as a hacky way.

**1. Go to **Custom Definitions** section and create a custom definition.**

Your scope should be "User". Select firebase_exp_`<N>` as the User property. Because Firebase defines a property for each user it adds to the experience. You can find the `<N>` number from the link on your A/B test page.

E.g. your A/B test link is like: `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/your-project/config/experiment/results/20`. The `<N>` number is 20 and user property is firebase_exp_20.

[image: create custom dimension]

**2. Create Audience for each control group**

Create a new audience according to this created dimension value. A value of 0 corresponds to **Baseline**. Each control group after that continues with consecutive numbers. (1,2,3..)

[image]

**3. Go to Analytics**

Go to Analytics and do your analysis for each control group with these Audiences.

I hope it helps.